# Insert records into MYSQL Database azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to copy data from sftp to Mysql,i try to use azure logic app,the problem i Don't know how to insert the file content csv into mysql database ,should i convert the csv file into json?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've done, where you're stuck, etc. As written, this is very broad and opinion-soliciting.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to convert CSV file to JSON as because Logic app runs on JSON after that you need to create the MY SQL connection in logic app for that you need to pass the on-prem gateway connection name

Here is the document to pass [on-prem gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) and here is the document for [inserting data in logic apps](https://www.tech-findings.com/2017/06/Inserting-data-in-On-Premises-SQL-Database-using-Logic-Apps.html)

Comment: FYI the question itself is very broad and high level. Further: no, you don't *need* to convert CSV to JSON - there are different approaches that can be taken. And I'm not sure why you're sharing a link to installing an on-premises gateway - that has nothing to do with the OP's question. Please avoid posting  1) answers to non-programming questions, 2) answers to broad/unclear questions showing no work, and 3) answers that are just links.